# Ireport IF Else Expression

Tags: ireport

I have this expression in iReport.:

```
($F{Q3_February}==0)?"-":$F{Q3_February}
```

Expression class is `Double`, I want this to returns as "-" if the value of `$F{Q3_February}` is `0`.

I get "-" only if I change it to Expression class `String` but the problem is if the value is false it doesn't return a value of `#,##0.00 %`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the textField pattern is not applied if the expression class is not numeric. You are trying to conditionally change not only the value, but also the class. This is not possible with a single textField.

I think your best bet is to separate this into two textFields, one string and one double. Place them on top of each other and then use `printWhenExpression`s to hide the one that is not wanted. The end result will be similar to having a single field with a conditional expression, but gives you more flexibility with the other element properties (i.e. class and pattern).

Example:

```
<textField pattern="#,##0.00 %">
    <reportElement x="200" y="80" width="100" height="20">
        <printWhenExpression>
            <![CDATA[$F{Q3_February}!=0]]>
        </printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Double">
        <![CDATA[$F{Q3_February}]]>
    </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField>
    <reportElement x="200" y="80" width="100" height="20">
        <printWhenExpression>
            <![CDATA[$F{Q3_February}==0]]>
        </printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
        <![CDATA["-"]]>
    </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: hi genericjon... thanks for the response this is actually what i did as workaround.. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There are a few alternative ways [to GenericJon's suggestion to solve this]:

1. With 4.1.1 there is a field on text boxes called "Pattern Expression" it is a field based
   field formatting option
2. You can format the field before it goes into the dataset [not recommended but works]
3. Lastly, you can call a scriptlet and pass in the values of the fields within the text section of the textbox.

> ```
> [Define Scriptlet name="bob"]
> <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String">
> <!CDATA[$P{[bob]_SCRIPTLET}.formatValues(fields1:n..)]]></textFieldExpression>
> ```